# How to edit a heroku facebook app?

Tags: facebook, git, heroku

I am very very new to heroku and Git, someone please help me.. where are the local project files located in my system.I have created a facebook app following this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook .I have a URL generated for my app and it runs fine.How do i edit this app.They have shown a sample of editing index.erb file in views folder and I am not able to find it.Where are the project source files?I know this sounds very basic and trivial but then I dont know and I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source files are on your computer right where you called "git clone" (see dev center link). With "git clone", you get the source code downloaded to your folder.

Here´s another tutorial for Heroku: http://www.devils-heaven.com/heroku-free-ssl-facebook-apps/

Btw, Heroku can be complicated for a beginner, i´d suggest using another webhost without GIT.